# Client-side caching when using CSP with nonces in nginx - how do you use weak caching validators/etags?

Tags: nginx, cache, etags, content-security-policy, http-caching

I'm using [nginx's `expires` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires); its [`etag` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag) as well as the [`Last-Modified` header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#if_modified_since) (if I understand correctly) are on by default.

In order to allow specific inline JavaScripts when using restrictive [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp) headers (i.e. no `'unsafe-inline'` resource policy) I want to use nonces.

I've basically followed [the article by Scott Helme on the matter](https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-nonce-support-in-nginx/), using nginx's `$request_id` in my trial to create the `nonce` [as discussed on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/934801/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-nginx-request-id-for-csp-nonce-value) (in order to try this quickly without having to build nginx from scratch).

When I tried this it seemed that caching no longer worked as I expected, however:
Nginx responded with the file and fresh `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers each time, instead of the `304 Not Modified` response I was hoping for.

Thinking about it, it makes sense: the `nonce` in the CSP header as well as in the source code changes with each request. However, nothing else changes. So, arguably, this is a change that a ["weak validator"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-13.3.3) should ignore (and thus mark the requested resource as *not* changed).

Having said that, I know very little to nothing about server configuration, or caching headers, for that matter. Chances are the smattering of knowledge I have isn't helping, and that weak validators, for example, aren't supposed to work that way, anyway.

Additionally, there seems to be [an issue that browsers get confused](https://melkfl.es/article/2018/05/csp-nonce/) when they have a cached version of the file with the old `nonce` but get a `304 Not Modified` header with a new `nonce` (although I haven't seen that myself in my trial).

My question is thus basically: is it possible to configure nginx so that caching works in a way where **changes to the `nonce` only** (i.e. changes that happen on the fly by text replacement) **are ignored when nginx creates the `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers** (i.e. where it only looks at the file changes on disk) - effectively using what are probably weak validators?

And, assuming browser confusion is an issue, can you do something to stop it, like not return a CSP header when the server returns 304 (so as not to replace the "header" nonce the browser has by a new one that then doesn't match the "file" one)? (This is more an academic question; I suppose I could somehow try not to set the CSP header for a `304` response, maybe using the [`ngx_headers_more` module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module).)

Do I effectively have the choice between using nonces or caching? Or should this work out of the box (and whatever I saw was down to something else)?